# MIPS. Count an amount of each ascii symbol in a string.

Tags: string, assembly, ascii, mips

I am trying to complete a task in MIPS.

It is needed to compare 2 strings in the next way: to count a number of each ascii symbol from 1 to 255 in both strings and and compare values for each symbol. 
For a moment i have wrote piece of pseudo code in java just to visualize a problem. The part that i can't understand is how can i make a "search" of each ascii character in a string.

```
 // array allAscii that suppose to contain all ascii  symbols (i have made it
 containing all zeros bacause in this java code it is not that much important)
int[] allAscii = new int[255]               

String s1 = "ascii.";   // first string
String s2 = "asciiz,";   // second string    

int difference = 0;    

for(int i = 0; i< allAscii.length; i++){

    int count1 = 0;       //counter for the character of the string1
    int count2 = 0;       //counter for the character of the string1

    for(int k = 0; k<s1.length(); k++){
        if( s1.charAt(k) == allAscii[i]) count1++;              
    }           
    for(int l = 0; l<s2.length(); l++){
        if( s2.charAt(l) == allAscii[i]) count2++;
    }

    difference += Math.abs(count1- count2);         
}
```

so as the result for strings "ascii." and "asciiz,"

symbols from 0 to 43:   count1 = 0; count2 = 0; difference = 0;

',':   count1 = 0; count2 = 1; difference = 1;

'.':   count1 = 1; count2 = 0; difference = 1;

symbols from 47 to 96:    count1 = 0; count2 = 0; difference = 0;

'a':   count1 = 1; count2 = 1; difference = 0;

'c':   count1 = 1; count2 = 1; difference = 0;

'i':   count1 = 2; count2 = 2; difference = 0;

's':   count1 = 1; count2 = 1; difference = 0;

'z':   count1 = 0; count2 = 1; difference = 1;

and so on....

it is non needed to store amount of each letter. i need just to accumulate variable difference but i should run through ALL ascii symbols

Comment: Exactly like you did in the pseudocode. Can you do loops and array indexing in MIPS? That's all you need.

Comment: @Jester how can i point that i need a first element of an array of ascii symbols? i can find out if a character is compressed between 'a' and 'z' like this:
sge $t0, $a0, 'a'
sle $t1, $a0, 'z'
but how can i "iterate" on the whole ascii array?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you follow your java code, declare an array with your characters, then load its starting address into a register, e.g. `la $a0, allAscii` then increment it in a loop and access the items as `($a0)`.

Comment: Check some ASCII table, ordinary ASCII is 7 bit value (0-127), usually stored as 8 bit byte (0-255) (wasting 1 bit). Your Java example tries to work with 255 characters, that's almost the full byte range (0-255 is 256 values, not 255), that's called "extended ASCII" and differs on each platform a lot (definition of 128-255 characters). Anyway, if you will think about it for a while, you will realize that your Java code is designed in such way, that `i == allAscii[i]`, so you can remove that char array completely and just loop through 0-255 byte values. Like the letter `'A'` IS byte value `65`.

Comment: I mean `sge $t0, $a0, 'A'` and `sge $t0, $a0, 65` is the same instruction, the `'A'` letter is actually number value after compilation, the computer itself has no idea about alphabet/letters or other characters, it sees just bits set/cleared, grouped by 8 bits, which can be interpreted either as 8 bit unsigned value "byte" ranging from 0 to 255 (Java has "signed" byte, so it is interpreting the same set of 8 bits as values from -128 to +127), or if you treat it as ASCII value, and display on screen font glyph of value `65`, then usually ordinary font will contain big letter A on that index.

Comment: @Ped7g thank you! You've helped me a lot!